# Single and double quotes in textfield, how to make them visible?

Tags: php, html, textfield

How can you make single and double quotes visible inside a text field? The data is retrived from a database. For example:

```
//PHP code
$sor = mysqli_fetch_assoc($eredmeny);
$string = $sor['this_is_a_string_with_qoutes'];

//HTML with PHP
<input type="text" name="1" id="1" value="<?php echo $string?>">
```

But if the string has got double qoutes the whole string will not show inside the textfield, just the part up to the first quote. I mean if my string is `BANANA"RAMA` it will only show `BANANA`

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Yeah, i can use that way, but is there no way to visible normally? without \ ?

Comment: @bwoebi ``\`` doesn't mean anything in HTML!

Comment: You can also use their ascii value in `#&...;`

Comment: @deceze Oh, just confused the markup and php sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
printf('<input type="text" name="1" id="1" value="%s">',
       htmlspecialchars($string));
```

HTML escape the data. **All data** you're outputting into HTML, in fact. See [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).